# How can I define a query as a variable in sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I was wondering if there was a way to save a query as a variable and use it later on, instead of dealing with inline subqueries. Is there a way to do this in SQLite3?

An example query of mine would be:

```
select Name
from (
    select Name, Count(*) c
    from branch
    group by Name
) f
where f.c = 1;
```

I would like to define the subquery f as a variable and then use it in this fashion, if possible:

```
select Name
from f
where f.c = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create in memory temp table and store the result of subquery and can use it later

```
  CREATE TEMP TABLE f(Name TEXT , NameCount INTEGER);

  INSERT into f 
  select Name, Count(*) c
  from branch
  group by Name;

  DROP TABLE if exists f; -- to clean up the temp table
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked with the exception of a semicolon at the end of the insert statement. I made an edit to clear it up. :)